# How to attach timestamp for each query in Influxdb and Grafana?

Tags: grafana, influxdb

I want to attach timestamp for each query in Influxdb using Grafana. For example:

I want to achieve something like this

```
      x  time(x)   y   time(y)
a     1    2       3     4 
b     5    6       7     8

SELECT x+time(x) FROM measurement WHERE name GROUP BY name
SELECT y+time(y) FROM measurement WHERE name GROUP BY name
```

But what I get right now is just like this

```
       x    y    time
a      1    -      2
a      -    3      4
b      5    -      6
b      -    7      8
```

Is there any way to achieve timestamp stick with its value for each query like the above?

Thank you